# Copy Gray Scale Image Content to 3 Channels

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am loading gray scale images in batches using `ImageDataGenerator`. I need to copy the content of every gray scale image into 3 channels. I have tried following code but it seems it is not working:

```
def grayscale_to_rgb(images, channel_axis=-1):
images= K.expand_dims(images, axis=channel_axis)
tiling = [1] * 4    # 4 dimensions: B, H, W, C
tiling[channel_axis] *= 3
images= K.tile(images, tiling)
return images




train_images_orign= grayscale_to_rgb(train_images_orign)
valid_images_orign= grayscale_to_rgb(valid_images_orign)
test_images_orign= grayscale_to_rgb(test_images_orign)

x_train, y_train = next(train_images_orign)
x_valid, y_valid = next(valid_images_orign)
x_test, y_test = next(test_images_orign)
```

In which direction I should look to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** It turns out that [`load_img`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/f3244289764539a3398e1289fc875d90aa7c63be/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L467) function in Keras has been implemented [in such a way](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/f3244289764539a3398e1289fc875d90aa7c63be/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L499) that if the color mode of the image being loaded and the given `color_mode` argument (which by default is `'RGB'`), differs then the image will be converted to given `color_mode`. As a result, in this case the grayscale image would be automatically converted to RGB.

---

You can use the `preprocessing_function` argument of [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class) as well (assuming you are using `color_mode='grayscale'`, otherwise the note above applies):

```
import numpy as np

def gray_to_rgb(img):
    return np.repeat(img, 3, 2)

generator = ImageDataGenerator(..., preprocessing_function=gray_to_rgb)
train_gen = generator.flow_from_directory(color_mode='grayscale', ...)
```

Just note that this function is applied after any image augmentation:

> **preprocessing_function:** function that will be implied on each input.
>   The function will run after the image is resized and augmented. The
>   function should take one argument: one image (Numpy tensor with rank
>   3), and should output a Numpy tensor with the same shape.

Comment: Now, I am getting error: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (227,227,9) into shape (227,227,3)

Comment: I printed the shape and it was (227,227,3). The reason for that is by default, ImageDataGenerator converts gray scal to RGB. So, actually I had nothing to do.

Comment: @PervaizNiazi You are right. The `load_img` is implemented [in such a way](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/f3244289764539a3398e1289fc875d90aa7c63be/keras_preprocessing/image.py#L499) that if the color mode of the image and the `color_mode` argument (which by default is RGB) differs, then it will be automatically converted to `color_mode`. However, I don't know what conversion method is used for converting grayscale to RGB in PIL module (which is used for loading images in Keras).

Comment: @devssh we did not need to modify any thing as ImageDataGenerator by default converts gray scale to RGB.In my case, all images are gray scale. Below is code: trainpath='C:/Users/datasets/train'
train_images_orign = ImageDataGenerator().flow_from_directory(trainpath,target_size =(224,224),classes=['Memo','Scientific','Resume'],batch_size = 64)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a direct way to convert it using ImageDataGenerator but I had the same problem a few days back and indirectly you can use opencv2 to convert it to rgb then I read it using imageio to numpy.

```
import cv2
cv2.imread('path/to/img/a.png') # look at glob for reading from folder
cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
cv2.imwrite('path/to/output/a.png')

import imageio
import skimage.transform as transform

image_size = 64
dimensions=4
array = []
for image_path in glob.glob("path/to/output/*.png"):
    try:
        im = imageio.imread(image_path)
        array = [*array, transform.resize(im, (image_size, image_size, dimensions))]
        array_names = [*array_names, image_path.split("output/")[1].split(".png")[0]]
    except ValueError:
        ""

np.array(array).shape
```

The expand_dims can be used as follows with tensorflow 1.10.1 helper methods which are closely tied to ImageDataGenerator to directly do the same but you will have to convert it from gray2rgb somehow which can improve this answer.

```
preprocess_input = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.preprocess_input
preds = model.predict(preprocess_input(np.expand_dims(array[0], axis=0))) # where model is some keras model
```

You will need the following to decode the output

```
decode_predictions = tf.keras.applications.resnet50.decode_predictions
decode_predictions(preds, top=3)
```

If this does not solve your problem or at least provide a template for solutions please leave a comment and i'll update it accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a better solution, which is to write a wrapper layer

```
class MyPreprocess( Layer ) :
    def call( self, inputs ) :
        # expand your input from gray scale to rgb
        # if your inputs.shape = (None,None,1)
        fake_rgb = K.concatenate( [inputs for i in range(3)], axis=-1 ) 
        fake_rgb = K.cast( fake_rgb, 'float32' )
        # else use K.stack( [inputs for i in range(3)], axis=-1 ) 
        # preprocess for uint8 image
        x = preprocess_input( fake_rgb )
        return x
    def compute_output_shape( self, input_shape ) :
        return input_shape[:3] + (3,)


gray_in = Input(shape=(None,None,1), name='gray_uint8')
tensor_in = MyPreprocess(name='preproc')( gray_in )
pred_out = PretrainedModel( tensor_in )
new_model = Model( inputs=gray_in, outputs=pred_out )
```

In this way, the `new_model` can be directly used to predict a `unit8` image.